# Itextsharp: How to place text at the middle of a page

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using the code below to create a Title page.

```
public static byte[] CreatePageHeader(List<string> texts) {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            doc.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
            doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Width, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Height));
            Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10f, Font.NORMAL);
            doc.Open();

            Paragraph para = null;
            foreach (string text in texts) {
                para = new Paragraph(text, font);
                doc.Add(para);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            doc.Close();
        }

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

this works fine, but it shows the Text at the top of the page.
But I want it at the middle of the page.

Please how do I modify this code do this?

Comment: Have you tried to add some empty paragraphs?

Comment: I thought of that, but I feel they should be an easier way.

Comment: Create a table and leave some empty rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just a single row, single column table for this. These kinds of objects support setting a fixed width/height which allows you to "center" things.

```
var outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");
using (var fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            //Create a single column table
            var t = new PdfPTable(1);

            //Tell it to fill the page horizontally
            t.WidthPercentage = 100;

            //Create a single cell
            var c = new PdfPCell();

            //Tell the cell to vertically align in the middle
            c.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            //Tell the cell to fill the page vertically
            c.MinimumHeight = doc.PageSize.Height - (doc.BottomMargin + doc.TopMargin);

            //Create a test paragraph
            var p = new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam iaculis sem diam, quis accumsan ipsum venenatis ac. Pellentesque nec gravida tortor. Suspendisse dapibus quis quam sed sollicitudin.");

            //Add it a couple of times
            c.AddElement(p);
            c.AddElement(p);

            //Add the cell to the paragraph
            t.AddCell(c);

            //Add the table to the document
            doc.Add(t);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```